# Why is there no sex in Brandon Sanderson's books?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, stormlight-archive, brandon-sanderson

I've read Brandon Sanderson's *Mistborn* and *Stormlight Archive* series, and I noticed that there are hardly any (if any) references to sexual activity between characters. I find that the author paints otherwise very gritty, full, and realistic pictures of characters' behavior and psychology—covering basically all aspects of the human condition *except for* sex. Is that deliberate, or am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't this true for pretty much all fantasy and sci/fi written by American authors though? Sanderson, Jordan, Collins, Brooks, Lucas etc etc... with RR Martin standing out as one exception.

Comment: Sometimes a story doesn't need sex.  Call it "Chekov's sex scene."  Is it an integral part of the story?  Nope, leave it out.  You might ask well as why there aren't more scenes about people clipping their toenails.  You do it, I do it, does jack to advance the story so leave it out.

Comment: @Amarth Joe Haldeman is a counterexample.

Comment: @Amarth Jordan was a bit more explicit about sex than Sanderson.  For example we at least know when and how Rand lost his virginity directly from the story.  Sanderson is definitely on the far end of that spectrum.  That said... I never really noticed the lack of sex in Sanderson's work coming from WoT, because it's still generally not a main draw of popular fantasy books.

Comment: @Amarth - I wouldn't say so at all. That's a narrow selection of authors, mostly old or dead, from a narrow subsection of the fantasy genre. Even in secondary world epic fantasy, counter-examples are easy to come by: N.K. Jemisin, Jim Butcher, Kai Ashante Wilson, later Ursula Le Guin (although also dead).

Comment: @Adamant Umm, no... I just pulled some of the most famous ones, from very diverse genres. George Lucas is dead and representing a narrow subsection of fantasy? Ok...

Comment: @Amarth - Brandon Sanderson, Terry Brooks, and Robert Jordan all wrote or write a specific class of secondary-world epic fantasy, which is a small portion of fantasy (compare urban fantasy, science fantasy, historical fantasy, non-epic secondary-world fantasy). George Lucas certainly wrote a  somewhat different style, though more similar than it might seem, epic secondary-world fantasy in SPACE and he certainly is old. I don't know who you mean by "Collins," but if you mean Paul Collins, he's Australian and born in England, and seems to write a similar class of fiction to the first three.

Comment: The point is, those four or five authors write in a similar genre, minus some aesthetic difference in the case of Lucas. They're demographically not so dissimilar: for instance, all but one of them is over 60. And even *within* the constraint of the genre they write in, secondary-world epic fantasy, I can think of at least four authors who have plenty of sex in their books, the ones I mentioned.

Comment: @Amarth Some of the giants of American Sci-Fi certainly have sex scenes: Larry Niven, William Gibson, and just this guy you might have heard of named Robert Heinlein. I grudgingly include Piers Anthony as well. Not because of the quality of any of his writing but because of the copious amounts of copulation in some of his series.

Comment: @Adamant Suzanne Collins who wrote Hunger Games, with teenager protagonists.

Comment: @Amarth - That's not even fantasy. Oh, but I guess you did say sci-fi. OK, I'll grant that that's a totally different genre. But perhaps not the best example, because for her relatively-free-of-sex young adult novel, I could list dozens that have sex (or even lots of sex), starting with *Breaking Dawn*. This is YA we're talking about.

Comment: @JRE To clarify, I wasn't saying that he SHOULD include sex, only that I found it oddly missing. I don't think the analogy to clipping toenails is apt, since sex greatly affects people's inner thoughts and outward behavior--things that Sanderson books otherwise seem intent on painting a full picture of.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Brandon Sanderson is a practicing Mormon, a religion which is not big on glorifying sex. He kind of commented on this in his site's FAQ entry about [why violence and swearing exists in his books](https://faq.brandonsanderson.com/knowledge-base/why-is-there-language-sex-violence-etc-in-your-books/).

> My books are about hope, in my opinion. Hope, struggle, and victory. I’ve tried very hard to keep graphic descriptions out of my books where I can, but I can’t always do so without undermining the story.
>
> A wise friend (an LDS writer) once explained that in his opinion, glorifying violence or sexuality comes when consequences are removed. The scriptures themselves don’t shy away from graphic content or descriptions (scalps on swords, anyone?) The important issue, however, is that the scriptures show the destructive effect that these things can have, even on the good people who are forced to engage in them.

And here is [a more direct quote regarding sex](https://www.reddit.com/r/brandonsanderson/comments/6egdxb/are_all_sanderson_books_devoid_of_sex_and/dia3vap?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) (bolding mine):

> Storytime. When I was working on Mistborn 2 with my editor, he asked me, "Are Vin and Elend sleeping together?" I said, "Absolutely." He requested some confirmation of it on the page, and I explained something that has always been my policy, and one that has served me well. **I consider what I'm writing to be a very detailed script, which you the reader direct in your mind.** Each person's version of the books will be slightly different, but in sometimes telling ways. The subtext of conversations will change, the visualizations of the characters, even larger implications are changed, distorted, and played with by the reader as they build the story in their imagination. **This is an area in which I prefer to leave the answers to the reader.** For those who wish to imagine that the characters are having sex, then the implications are often there. (Though I've gotten better at that balance, I feel.) **For those who don't want to imagine it, and wish to pretend the characters are living different standards, I will often leave the opportunity for that**--unless it is a plot point I consider relevant. **Certainly, my upbringing and beliefs are an influence on this. I'm obviously more circumspect in these areas than I am in others.** But yes, for those who don't want to pretend otherwise, Vin and Elend were sleeping together. And Wax and Lessie never had a real ceremony. My editor tried to remove the word "wife" from one of the later books, and I insisted, as the shift in Wax's thinking was a deliberate point on my part--related to his changing psychology in the books. But even to him, it's more a 'common law wife' thing. As a side note you'll likely find amusing, I do get a surprising number of emails from people who complain to me (even take me to task) for the amount of objectionable material I include in my books, and ask me why I have to wallow in filth as much as I do. I'm always bemused by this, as I doubt they have any idea how the books are perceived in this area by the general fantasy reading world...

And ultimately, it may just be personal preference. I'm listening to some of his [Writing Excuses podcast episodes with the sex-scenes tag](https://writingexcuses.com/tag/sex-scenes/), but it may just be something that he doesn't find easy to write.

> Shanna Germain joins Brandon, Mary, and Howard in front of a live audience at GenCon Indy to talk about writing love scenes. They’re not easy to get right, and they can be even more difficult to talk about it in a way that leaves the Writing Excuses team’s “clean” rating intact.

In fact, he delegates most of the episode to Shanna in the Season 7 episode because, to quote him, "I am a prude". In Season 8, Episode 1, he specifically states that he prefers the offhand mention that activities were going on without getting into detail, although he respects people who can make such activities an integral part of the story.

Comment: I think this is bang on. Intentional or not, his religious views are very evident through his works. I knew nothing about the author but by the end of Mistborn I was convinced he was some form of Christian, wasn't surprised at all to find this confirmed!

Comment: His notes in Warbreaker make this _very_ clear how uncomfortable he gets writing intimate scenes even _without_ sex.

Comment: @DavidS I figured out immediately that he was a Mormon, based on the consistent presence of corrupted Gods and men becoming Gods. LDS happens to have a great mythology which hasnt been explored by writers, as opposed to mainstream Christianity, which has been done to death.